# REGEX para sustituir -- por --- en TeXstudio

Tags: regex, latex

Necesito un REGEX que me permita sustituir contenido como este:

```
--Lorem ipsum--
```

Por esto:

```
---Lorem ipsum---
```

Estoy intentando esto (hay un espacio en blanco antes y despúes):

```
--.*?--
```

Pero me alcanza también contenido con tres `-`.

¿Cuál sería el REGEX para alcanzar únicamente los que tengan dos `-` y luego reemplazar eso por tres `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el punto (.) representa cualquier carácter (excepto salto de línea). Por tanto, también hace match con el guión (-).

Suponiendo que entre los dos pares de guiones debe haber al menos un carácter, pero en ningún caso un guión, deberás usar `[^-]` que representa eso, cualquier carácter excepto el guión.

Entonces te quedaría así: `--[^-]+--`

Como quieres añadir un guión a cada lado, sería: `(--[^-]+--)` (dejando los espacios a los lados para evitar sustituirlos).

Y la cadena de reemplazo sería `-\1-`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Probé el REGEX que me sugieres, pero no me funciona de la forma esperada. Este REGEX me alcanza el contenido que tiene `---` también. Yo quiero que me alcance solamente el que tenga `--`  para sustituirlo por `---` precisamente.

Comment: A mí sí me está funcionando. ¿Es posible que en la búsqueda no hayas dejado el espacio en blanco antes y después que indicabas en la pregunta?

Comment: Guillermo sí, he puesto espacio en blanco antes y después para aislar los dos `- ` pero aún así alcanza a los que tienen tres `-`

Comment: Guillermo disculpa, lo he probado de nuevo y funciona... a veces me da la impresión de TeXstudio guarda búsquedas en memoria o algo así, pues a veces no funciona ni siquiera con búsquedas simples (no encuentra los términos) y al cabo de un rato funciona. Con tu REGEX me pasó algo parecido. Ahora funcionó. Gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro de que te haya servido.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que lo único que necesitas es obtener los **dos** guiones de la izquierda y los **dos** de la derecha y reemplazarlos por ***tres***, también ocupas **espacios** o **letras** de una palabra, entonces simplemente podríamos:

```regex
Grupo 1: dos guiones a la izquierda
Grupo 2: repetir espacios o letras de una palabra mas de una vez
Grupo 3: dos guiones a la derecha
(--)([\s\w]+)(--)
```

De manera que lo que debes hacer es reemplazar al **grupo uno** y **grupo tres** por `---` y luego reemplazar todo:

```
Grupo1="---"
Grupo3="---"
# una vez reemplazado solo lo imprimes o lo guardas
AsiQueda="$Grupo1+$Grupo2+$Grupo3"
```

Comment: No necesito exactamente dos palabras separadas por un espacio, lo del `Lorem ipsum` es un ejemplo, pero puede haber muchas más palabras, yo necesito reemplazar simplemente los dos guiones por tres guiones sin importar la cantidad de palabras que haya entre ellos.

Comment: @A.Cedano entre el par de guiones de cada lado, ¿que caracteres pueden existir?